# Can scripts in iframe interact with scripts in the main page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an editor with an SWF multi-image uploader. Since not everyone will need to upload pictures in their article, i need to dynamically load this image uploader when necessary. I have to load it in an iframe because the uploader needs some external scripts to be loaded ahead. And since i need it's callback variable for my editor to use I want to know whether scripts in iframe can interacts with scripts in the main page. Or if i can't do that, what's the alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they are on the same domain, yes.

The `parent` object is the parent window of the iframe.

If you had a variable `a` in the global scope of the parent window, you could manipulate it in the iframe like this:

```
parent.a = "new value";
```

Similarly, if `a` is a function in the global scope of the parent window, you could call it like this:

```
parent.a(args);
```

Answer (score 4):

postMessage in Html5, supported by Internet Explorer 8.0+, Firefox 3.0+, Safari 4.0+, Chrome 1.0+ and Opera 9.5+, is how I have been using it. If you don't mind the lack of support in IE7 and earlier versions, here's how to implement it.

Javascript in the main window:

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);  

function receiveMessage(event){ 
    var source = event.source.frameElement; //this is the iframe that sent the message
    var message = event.data; //this is the message
    //do something with message
}
```

Javascript in the iframe;

```
var message='hello, big window!'; //could be of any type, string, number, array, object, have fun
window.parent.postMessage(message,'*'); //the '*' has to do with cross-domain messaging. leave it like it is for same-domain messaging.
```

Of course you could do it the other way round, having the main window sending messages to the iframe, and have some cross-window dialogue that way.

Comment: Is it possible to exchange between two iframes this way, or is it only for parent-child communication?

Answer (score 1):

To extend Andy's answer [Can scripts in iframe interact with scripts in the main page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502047/can-scripts-in-iframe-interact-with-scripts-in-the-main-page/7502372#7502372) :

Use jQuery.postMessage plugin http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-postmessage/docs/files/jquery-ba-postmessage-js.html

Browsers Tested Internet Explorer 6-8, Firefox 3, Safari 3-4, Chrome, Opera 9.

Answer (score 0):

> Can scripts in iframe interact with scripts in the main page

Only if the iframe and its parent have the exact same domain, due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) ([MDC link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)).

Answer (score 0):

If the iframe is from a different domain, but you have control over the content, you can communicate between the two in a couple different ways. The simplest is to "talk" through key/value pairs in the URL of the iFrame, since both the parent and the iFrame have access to that.

A more complicated approach is to use iFrame proxy's, which is described really well here: http://www.julienlecomte.net/blog/2007/11/31/ which uses Yahoo Pipes to send messages back and forth quite nicely.