# PhantomJS + Trigger a button click inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS with options --web-security=false. I have an HTML page that embeds a page in an iframe:

```html
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Test page</TITLE>
    <script   src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  </HEAD>
<BODY>
  <HR align="left" width="300">
    <P>
      <b>New frame:</b>
   <div id="newframe">
      <iframe id="card_pay_2" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" src="https://money.yandex.ru/embed/small.xml?any-card-payment-type=on&amp;uid=410014480752241&amp;button-text=01&amp;button-size=m&amp;button-color=black&amp;targets=JetChange 31036&amp;default-sum=2040&amp;successURL=https://jetchange.com/success" width="auto" height="54">
      </iframe>
   </div>
    </P>
  <HR align="left" width="300">
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

iframe load follow HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
<html class="i-ua_js_yes i-ua_css_standart utilityfocus i-ua_svg_yes i-        ua_inlinesvg_yes i-ua_placeholder_yes" id="js">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="b-widget-button b-widget-button_black b-widget-button_m">
    <form method="POST" target="_blank" action="/quickpay/confirm.xml">
        <input name="label" type="hidden" value="">
        <input name="receiver" type="hidden" value="410014480752241">
        <input name="quickpay-form" type="hidden" value="small">
        <input name="referer" type="hidden" value="">
        <input name="is-inner-form" type="hidden" value="true">
        <input type="hidden" name="targets" value="JetChange 31036">
        <input type="hidden" name="sum" value="2040" maxlength="8">
        <input type="hidden" name="successURL"    value="https://jetchange.com/success">
        <input type="hidden" name="paymentType" value="AC">
        <span class="b-button" data-content-block="this">
            <img class="b-widget-button__icon b-widget-button__icon_type_any-  card" src="/i/b-widget-button__icon_type_any-card.png">
            <span class="b-button__inner">Перевести</span>
            <input type="submit" class="b-button__input">
        </span>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to click the button into the iframe. Is it possible ?
I tried the following variants of code. It didn't work:

```
1. page.evaluate(function() {
  $('iframe').contents().find("form[target='_blank']").submit();            --> didn't work
  $('iframe').contents().find("form[target='_blank']").trigger('submit');   --> didn't work
});
2. page.switchToFrame(0);
   page.evaluate(function(){
  var frm = document.querySelector('form[target=_blank]');
  frm.click();                                                  --> didn't work
  frm.submit();                                                 --> didn't work
  frm.trigger('submit');                                        --> didn't work
});
page.switchToMainFrame();
3. page.switchToFrame(0);
   page.evaluate(function(){
  function click(elm){
    var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
    event.initMouseEvent('click', 
                          true, true, 
                          window, 0, 
                          0, 0, 0, 0,
                          false, false, false, false,
                          0, null);
    elm.dispatchEvent(event);                                   --> didn't work
  }
  var frm = document.querySelector('form[target=_blank]');
  click(frm);
});
page.switchToMainFrame();
4. page.switchToFrame(0);
   var point = page.evaluate(function(){
  var frm = document.querySelector('form[target=_blank]');
  var rect = frm.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: rect.left + (rect.width/2),
    y: rect.top + (rect.height/2)
  };
});
page.switchToMainFrame();
console.log('X: ' + point.x);
console.log('Y: ' + point.y);
page.sendEvent('click', point.x, point.y);                      --> didn't work
```

Comment: Did you use the **--web-security=no** switch? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15119484/2952074

Comment: I'm using PhantomJS with options --web-security=false