# JS trigger event on window.parent from iframe with timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, timeout, parent

I'm tyring to trigger an event on window.parent on button click from an iframe using jquery with a timeout of 2 seconds

My in-iframe Button:

```
<input id = 'submit' type = "submit" name = 'submit' value = "Save">
```

The JQuery Event:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    window.parent.setTimeout(function(){
        // some stuff ....
    }, 2000);

});
```

Well, this is working with Safari 7.0.3 and Chrome 34.0.1847.116 m
But in Firefox 28.0 and my current Version of IE11 i have no chance to get it working.

Does anyone know the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, are you ok with only allowing the newest browsers?

In that case you can use postMessage, one the click, you wait 2 seconds, then send a message telling the parent to trigger the event. This only works if you have control over both however.

[Can scripts in iframe interact with scripts in the main page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502047/can-scripts-in-iframe-interact-with-scripts-in-the-main-page)

This question above goes into more detail then I can above.

Comment: thanks this is accepted. however, i put a function myEvent() to the parent where i set the timeout and call it by window.parent.myEvent(). think it's a browser thing...

Comment: IE11 is new, so using a different approach could eliminate the specific problem you are having, it may not be a "fix" but given one of the browsers you listed as a problem is IE its my favorite approach to fix IE related issues (they are painful, in any version).